# How to clear surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to create a animation - first I draw a circle, then I want to redraw it.

```
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=5,cstride=5,color='r',linewidth=0.1,shade=0) # - this function
```

To redraw it in another place I have to delete it first. How can I do it? Just give me function, that allows me to remove last surface, or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=5,cstride=5,color='r',linewidth=0.1,shade=0) # - this function
sf.remove()
```